# Strange behavior of String's matches() method

Tags: java, regex, string

I encountered an interesting issue about String's matches(RegExp) method.

```
assertTrue("33CCFF".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));
assertTrue("CC33FF".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));
assertTrue("CC3355".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));
assertTrue("CC9955".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));
assertTrue("CC3366".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));
assertTrue("CC3965".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));
assertTrue("CC1961".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));
assertTrue("CC9999".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}"));
assertTrue("СС3966".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}")); // failing
assertTrue("СС9965".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}")); // failing
assertTrue("СС9966".matches("[0-9A-Za-z]{6}")); // failing
```

The last 3 assertion is failing unexpectedly. I couldn't find any reasons why this weird behavior is happening. Do you have the same issue? Do you have any ideas?

By the way, in case of being asked, my java version is the following.

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I investigated after your answers and noticed that upper C chars (&#0043) are different than lower C chars (&#1057). The C chars in the last 3 lines seem to be from Cyrillic alphabet. http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-ru.htm

Comment: The problem occurs due to user's input. To check if the input is alpha-decimal (even for Cyrillic C), org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isAlphanumeric() is returning true as the following: assertTrue(StringUtils.isAlphanumeric("\u0421\u0421")); // cyrillic C
assertTrue(StringUtils.isAlphanumeric("\u00E7\u00E7")); // ascii C

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The last three don't *actually* start with an ASCII "C" character. They start with a non-ASCII character which *looks* like "C". That doesn't match anything in the `[0-9A-Za-z]` set, hence the pattern fails.

(I found this out by copying and pasting the code into a text editor which doesn't handle non-ASCII characters terribly well - they came out as "?".)

Comment: Right, HEX code of the wrong-C-character is `0x3F` but for all previous `C` is `0x43`

Comment: @sll: No, the 3F is just "?" which is often used to represent characters which can't otherwise be represented. The character shown is *not* "?".

Comment: good catch! Looks like my editor replaced this character by `?` before saving

Answer (score 2):

your "СС3966" (I'm cutting and pasting) are getting flagged as non UTF-8, which is why reg-ex isn't matching them. When I change your text and just type it myself it works as expected.  Not sure where you copied these values from, but that's your problem

Comment: I got your point. You found out the issue as JonSkeet. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: It's funny... John and I found out the same answer, I found it 1 minute before he did... he gets 12 upvotes, I get 1 :) Looks like this is a popularity contest after all! lol.

Comment: btw, when I pasted your match into my eclipse and tried to save, IT brought up a dialog saying that I'm trying to save non UTF-8 text. I don't think I've modified my eclipse settings at all, so you should see why yours isn't giving you the same warning for future issues like this.